# How to deal with ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host '6.' (0) and garbage character when inserting large file into mysql?

Tags: mysql

I want to insert a large file (about 4G) into mysql. I used source command and tried several times. Every time at first everything go right like

> Query OK, 1710 rows affected (0.27 sec)
>
> Records: 1710  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

But after about ten minutes I got the following error message

> "ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host '--' (0)" with garbage character.

And it says that:

> No connection. Trying to reconnect...
>
> ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'rnrn' (0)
>
> ERROR:
>
> Can't connect to the server

With some garbage characters like:

> ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host '2銆佹嫑鍟嗛?鍝佹姇鏀鹃〉闈㈡惌寤鸿惀閿?椿鍔ㄤ竴浣撳寲娴佺▼鎼?缓rn' (0)
>
> ERROR:
>   Can't connect to the server

Could any one help?

I tried to change the parameters in `mysql.ini`

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1024M
; Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
innodb_log_file_size = 512M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 64M
```

change the number to:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 512M
; Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
innodb_log_file_size = 256M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 32M
```

or change the max_allowed_package from 1M to 1024M, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: You really want to put 4GB into a database? Just for performance reasons it's always better to put files into the file system and only reference them from the database.

Comment: Yes, cause it is the data of a project in a company and if I use the file system it is so slow for me since I need to use the vpn. I spend half an hour waiting for it. I almost cannot do anything but wait for the web. Do you have any solution or advice on how to insert it?

Answer (score 0):

If possible, the database dump should be split into smaller chunks, and inserted one by one. The problem may be caused by a time limit on the single database connection imposed by the server, or unstable connection.

I do not know how exactly to split the file, it depends on your database structure. It is possible to create structure for all tables in one file, and insert data in others. If foreign keys exist, they should be disabled on insert, otherwise you may end up adding data, dependencies for which are not yet defined.

Alternatively, you may try uploading the dump to the server, and import it from mysql using LOAD DATA INFILE, or using local mysql. But that requires an SSH connection to your server - not all providers allow it.